# Meeting point of opposing right triangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

> In the diagram below, $AB$, $EF$ and $DC$ are perpendicular to $BC$. $AEC$ and $BED$ are straight lines. $AB = x$, $EF = h$ and $DC = y$. Then how can $h$ be expressed?

Here is the image:

[image]

I drew the shape and used Pythagoras' theorem for the two triangles and made them equal to each other since both equal $h$. Then I used Pythagoras' theorem for the two large triangles and then I was stuck.

Comment: I believe you have enough rep to put the image in the question, and to know that proper MathJax formatting will help us help you!

Comment: Give your question an appropriate title, please. Make it descriptive and objective.

Comment: Then $h$ is what?

Comment: Is the question incomplete? You say "Then $h$ is" -- what? Is there a list of possibilities you are supposed to choose from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using similar triangles $$\frac hx=\frac{FC}{BC}\\\frac hy=\frac{BF}{BC}\\
\frac hx + \frac hy = 1\\h=\frac{xy}{x+y}$$

Comment: why is h/x +h/y =1???? @rossmillikan

Comment: @exchangehelpforuni $BF+FC=BC$

Comment: @rossmilikan I know why is BC=1??????

Comment: It is not.  But $\frac {BC}{BC}=1$  I am adding the two previous equations.  They are already over the common denominator $BC$

Answer (score 0):

Using only Thales Theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
&\text{On }\;\Delta BCD:\;\;\frac{BF}{BC}=\frac hy\implies h\stackrel1=\frac{BF}{BC}y\\{}\\
&\text{On}\;\;\Delta ABC:\;\;\frac{CF}{BC}=\frac hx\implies h\stackrel2=\frac{CF}{BC}x\end{align*}$$

Comparing both expressions for $\;h\;$ above:

$$y\,BF=x\,CF\implies\frac yx=\frac{CF}{BF}$$

and from here

$$h\stackrel1=\frac{BF}{BF+CF}y=\frac1{1+\frac{CF}{BF}}y=\frac1{1+\frac yx}y=\frac{xy}{x+y}$$